# Работа с функциями. Как вывести значение функции

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю как вывести значение из этой функции соответственно ( 1 , -1 или 0). Пока что выводится сама функция. Заранее спасибо

```
    var person1 = {
        name: "Greg",
        age: 30
    }
    var person2 = {
    name:"George",
        age:29
     }
function createComparisonFunction(propertyName){
return function(object1, object2){
    var value1 = object1[age];
    var value2 = object2[age];
    alert(value2.age);
    if (value1 > value2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (value2 > value1) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
};
}
alert(createComparisonFunction(age));
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить значение, возвращаемое функцией, функцию нужно вызвать. `createComparisonFunction` возвращает анонимную функцию с двумя параметрами, которую можно сохранить в промежуточную переменную `sravnivatel`. А уже ее вызов вернет 1, -1 или 0.

```
function createComparisonFunction(propertyName){
  return function(object1, object2) {
    var value1 = object1[propertyName];
    var value2 = object2[propertyName];
    if (value1 > value2) {
      return -1;
    } else if (value2 > value1) {
      return 1
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  };
}

var sravnivatel = createComparisonFunction("age");
var rezultat = sravnivatel(person1, person2);
alert(rezultat);
```

Comment: А не проще `alert(createComparisonFunction("age")(person1,person2))`

Comment: @Mike Меня тошнит, когда в строке слишком много скобок :). А так - конечно, можно.